# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, arm

I am getting the same issue as mentioned in below link.But this one has been put on hold and I am still seeking for a solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146511/panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpus-eclipse

So I would like to frame the question and ask here. Until yesterday, emulator were working fine. But since today I am receiving the following error while I am trying to open emulator

```
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS
```

My AVD:
[image: AVD]

This is the error I am receiving:

[image]

I have updated and installed components through SDK Manager and I even tried to restart eclipse and my pc as well.
I tried creating new AVD But nothing worked here.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I am also getting same error on android studio. It was working fine before some time but few minutes ago I am getting this error , I tried to update it but no luck

Comment: This is an SDK problem. I'd try updating or even reinstalling/putting a new copy somewhere, create a new device from the new/updated SDK and try again. I've had something similar happen a few weeks ago when android studio moved the SDK out of the AS main folder.

Comment: Here is the solution to Android Studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897046/mac-and-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpu/52161215#52161215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to Avast Antivirus, has found bunch of emulator-arm files in its quarantine. Problem started couple of hours ago.

What I did as temporary solution: restored emulator-arm from quarantine, added it to avast exception, paused Avast, run AVD, then resumed Avast

Comment: I have no avast and I have that problem

Answer (score 18):

In my case, my PATH environment variable was set incorrectly. It was including

`<sdk-path>/sdk/tools`

Instead of

`<sdk-path>/sdk/emulator`

`emulator.exe` exists in both of these directories, so the `emulator` command will work either way. However, `emulator-arm.exe` only exists in my `emulator` directory.

Answer (score 2):

This error happened to me when I re-formatted my computer and tried to copy and paste my old SDK files into my newly formatted computer.

I needed to re-download the SDK’s API stuff. For example, when I re-download API 19, it added these files in red and my Emulator for API 19 worked. API 18 & 17 kept giving me the "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS." error message. API 18 & 17 were the files I copied and pasted in.

Just delete everything and re-install it. Especially the Tools folder.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but I solved it differently from the others.  I was trying to create an emulator to test on an older Android version on my Mac.

My mistake was I had selected the wrong tab (see screenshot).  I should have clicked the "x86 Images" tab instead of the "Other Images" tab to avoid this error:

`Emulator: PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.`

[image]

Comment: This helps me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that there are some missing components in the Android SDK Tools!

In my case, for some reason, Avast Antivirus recognizes the tools/emulator-arm.exe as a threat and puts it in the virus chest!
This started happening since I've updated the SDK manager and everything to latest (tools 23.0.5)

Once I've restored the emulator-arm.exe file and disabled Avast for 10 minutes, I was able to start the emulator without problems!

Note: I've tried to add the file as exception to the Avast AV but it still removes the file from my system.

Please check if your SDK Tools installation is complete and update (delete first?) everything, or at least the Tools section in the SDK Manager!

I hope that helps!

Comment: Note: This seems to affect other files too, i.e. android-sdks\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error a few minutes ago. Look into antivirus chest and try to check if `emulator-arm.exe` is there. Try add the file to exception of antivirus.

It is working for me. (I have got avast!). Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the same time as you guys and I am also using Avast. But I could not find the file in the chest of Avast.

So what worked for me was to reinstall the Tools of Android SDK:

1. Open Android SDK Manager
2. Select Android SDK Tools
3. Click "Delete 1 package"
4. Once it is done, reselect Adroid SDK Tools and click "Install 1 package".

Hope it helps.

Comment: in case you want to know how to access virus chest in avast(my version is 2014.9.0.2018) check this link - https://blog.avast.com/2013/11/03/how-do-i-access-the-avast-virus-chest/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a crazy old topic, but I ran into this same problem and had a hard time solving it. This topic kept popping up on all the searches

The quick work around is to simply copy everything from
/sdk/tools To /sdk/emulator without overwriting anything.

My path looks like this
C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too this morning... and I've got Avast !
"Restore and add to exclusion" seems not to work in this case, so i manually added the exclusion...

Solution:

1- Go to Avast Control Panel > Scan > Quarantine > Right Click on "emulator-arm.exe" > Restore and add to exclusion...

2- From Avast Main Screen > Parameters > Active protection (2nd item) > File Agent (click on the wheel) > Exclusions (4th item on the left menu) > Add the complete file path of emulator-arm.exe at the bottom of the list.

Then it works for me...

Comment: repeated! Read other answers before, we have already several answers regarding Avast. You might edit those

Answer (score 0):

Avast Antivirus is sensing emulator-arm.exe as a thread and blocking from some reasons. When you add it exclusions in Virus Chest page with right-click -> "restore and add to exclusions" it's not solved in future runnings. To solve this permanently in Avast 2015 :

Settings ->

Active Protection ->

File System Shield ->

Customize ->

Exclusions then add thread as a exclusion . And then press ok.

Comment: repeated! Read other answers before, we have already several answers regarding Avast. You might edit those

Answer (score 0):

in my case,there was missing arm eabi v7a system image for api level 22. After downloading it started to work. so make sure that Your arm eabi v7a system image is installed for the particular API Level

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use an Android Virtual Device (AVD) with an Android Version, whose SDK platform version you have not installed, this error also appears.

Download all the Android SDK versions whose AVD you might use, i.e., be sure you have the **API level** installed whose AVD you will use.

Furthermore, check the first line the next image in the column CPU (this was also giving an error). Change the CPU of your AVD, to `x86` and then it will work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be the bugs / updates happened in the OS. So, instead of updating  in `.profile`, `/etc/environment`, or `.bashrc` file to point `adb`, `emulator` etc, put (copy and paste) all the `emulator` folder inside `/usr/bin` directory. Install `adb` tool from the terminal. This should solve everything.

And/Or, update your all environment variables in `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. Note that: `/etc/bash.bashrc` file is what gets executed everytime you open the bash terminal.