# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS. in Android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

Before some time everything was working fine, But now when I launch emulator I am getting error as

> PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS.

Here is screen shot

[image]

I had tried to update sdk manager, But there is nothing to update.

[image]

In extras everything is installed, But I think there is something missing in this package, But I don't know how to install that one. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

After clicking on help menu and check for updates I got message as You already have updated version as shown in image below
[image]

I also uninstall android sdk tools and reinstall it but still no luck

Comment: Did you do `Help/Check for updates`, after updating the SDK components?

Comment: @DerGolem  Yes and my updates/new check box is also selected as shown in second image, But there is no updates available therefore I cant install it

Comment: `Yes and my updates/new check box is also selected as shown in second image` This is **not** what I suggested (and I also suggested this before). I suggested that, AFTER CLOSING THIS SCREEN, select `Check for updates` from the `Help` menu. Hope I was finally clear.

Comment: @DerGolem  Yes I had also check it from Help Menu, But it says You already have the latest version, the screen is attached in my edited question. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150354/panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avast Antivirus is sensing emulator-arm.exe as a threat and blocking from some reasons. When you add it to exclusions in Virus Chest page with right-click -> "restore and add to exclusions" it's not solved in future runnings. To solve this permanently in Avast 2015 :

**Settings** ->

**Active Protection** ->

**File System Shield** ->

**Customize** ->

**Exclusions**    then add threat as a exclusion . And then press ok.

Answer (score 4):

I answered this in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452751/1445466).

In my case, my PATH environment variable was set incorrectly. It was including

/sdk/tools

Instead of

/sdk/emulator

emulator.exe exists in both of these directories, so the emulator command will work either way. However, emulator-arm.exe only exists in my emulator directory.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem but here [PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150354/panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpus?rq=1)  was helpful information

For some reasons Avast antivirus has considered emulator-arm as virus and put it to quarantine. And continues to do that. Check please if You have that AV soft

It started near hour-two ago so can be related to new "viruses definitions" of Avast that somewhy quarantines that files

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys after JakeM and Hnkonan response to my question I got answer to my question. First of all thanks to both.

The main reason was Avast antivirus. First of all I had disable avast after that I had open Virsu chest of it and I got there emulator-arm.exe file. I had restore it. After that I restart android studio. But at this time it giving me error as

> Android-Studio : Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

I had downloaded notepad++ then open android studio/bin folder in this bin folder there is one file name as studio.exe.vmoptions. Open this file file using notepad++ and change the -Xms128m to -Xms512m and restarted Android Studio.

After that I am able to launch emulator. Currently my Avast is disable but it may possible after enabling it will again move emulator-arm.exe file to virus chest. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in Eclipse. It looks like Avast thinks it is infected with Win32:Dropper-gen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Avast was blocking the files as @JakeM stated. After following what @PPD stated its working fine. Even when Avast is turned on. Not much of an answer but hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem with emulator-arm.exe in tools directory of sdk. Copy it from install package and everything will be OK

Comment: No it won't because the next time you run it, Avast! will just block it and put it back in the chest again.