# Mac and "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU."

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am attempting to run an AVD I have created for API 16 on a Galaxy Nexus:

```
emulator @Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16
```

which gives the error

> PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.

Attempting to start it by pressing the play button from the AVD Manager inside Android Studio bounces something briefly in the tool dock, but it quickly vanishes and nothing shows up and there are no obvious error messages.

I have looked through other posts with similar problems. Most cite Avast on Windows as causing the issue. I am running on a Mac. I do not have Avast installed.

The AVD has the following configuration:

```
Name: Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16
CPU/ABI: Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Path: /Users/prisoner/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_16.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 16)
Skin: galaxy_nexus
SD Card: 100 MB
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 1280
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Galaxy Nexus
vm.heapSize: 80
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.lcd.width: 720
hw.gps: yes
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 16
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/images/armeabi-v7a/
hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8
tag.id: google_apis
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16
hw.camera.front: emulated
hw.lcd.density: 320
avd.ini.displayname: Galaxy Nexus Jelly Bean API 16
hw.arc: false
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.device.hash2: MD5:5c288d27461585ecc73a535555e7cf61
hw.ramSize: 1024
hw.trackBall: no
PlayStore.enabled: false
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.sdCard: no
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Android Studio environment:

```
Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 23, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

I have installed everything for this version of the SDK available in the SDK Manager:

[image]

I have the latest version of the emulator installed. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing it.

[image]

The `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable appears to be correctly set (it matches the `Android SDK location` in the SDK Manager. The `emulator` program appears to be the one under this home environment as well:

```
Mulan:~ prisoner$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk
Mulan:~ prisoner$ which emulator
/Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

As far as I can tell, the emulator and the architecture-specific emulators are also under `ANDROID_HOME`:

[image]

I'm at a loss about where else to look, either for error messages or the emulator that is there, but can't be found by the system, or how else to address the problem.

**Update 1**: Specify path explicitly.

Trying to specify the paths explicitly doesn't work either:

```
Mulan:~ prisoner$ /Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator @Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.
Mulan:~ prisoner$ /Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

Sure enough, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` isn't defined. Defining it to the same thing as `ANDROID_HOME` does the following:

```
Mulan:~ prisoner$ export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_HOME"
Mulan:~ prisoner$ /Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (/Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk) but cannot find kernel file in /Users/prisoner/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/ sub directories
```

Looking underneath the `system-images` directory, we see a directory for each API platform:

```
Mulan:~ prisoner$ ls ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/
android-16  android-19  android-23  android-26
android-17  android-21  android-24  android-27
android-18  android-22  android-25  android-28
```

Looking just under the `android-16` directory, we have

```
./default
./default/armeabi-v7a
./default/armeabi-v7a/build.prop
./default/armeabi-v7a/kernel-qemu
./default/armeabi-v7a/NOTICE.txt
./default/armeabi-v7a/package.xml
./default/armeabi-v7a/ramdisk.img
./default/armeabi-v7a/source.properties
./default/armeabi-v7a/system.img
./default/armeabi-v7a/userdata.img
./default/mips
./default/mips/build.prop
./default/mips/kernel-qemu
./default/mips/NOTICE.txt
./default/mips/package.xml
./default/mips/ramdisk.img
./default/mips/source.properties
./default/mips/system.img
./default/mips/userdata.img
./default/x86
./default/x86/build.prop
./default/x86/kernel-qemu
./default/x86/kernel-ranchu
./default/x86/NOTICE.txt
./default/x86/package.xml
./default/x86/ramdisk.img
./default/x86/source.properties
./default/x86/system.img
./default/x86/userdata.img
./google_apis
./google_apis/x86
./google_apis/x86/advancedFeatures.ini
./google_apis/x86/build.prop
./google_apis/x86/kernel-qemu
./google_apis/x86/kernel-ranchu
./google_apis/x86/NOTICE.txt
./google_apis/x86/package.xml
./google_apis/x86/ramdisk.img
./google_apis/x86/source.properties
./google_apis/x86/system.img
./google_apis/x86/userdata.img
```

Comment: I've been having a similar issue on my Mac. This is however only for the x86 image variants. I have no issues with arm images and am able to run them via CLI. But through Android Studio AVD Manager I am able to run these images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried and verified on my Mac, to solve this problem, you need to specify the `-kernel` path manually. i.e.

```
$ ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator  @Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16 -kernel ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-16/default/armeabi-v7a/kernel-qemu
```

Some references for you:

1. [Emulator error: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9712605/8034839)
2. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

**--- Edit ---**

To avoid typing the `-kernel` argument every time, you can also copy the `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-16/default/armeabi-v7a/kernel-qemu` file to `~/Library/Android/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/images/armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: Excellent! Wish I understood why it was't finding it at that path on its own, but glad it works. Thanks for the help! The bounty is yours. {:

Comment: you want to use SDK/emulator/emulator  not the SDK/tools/emulator to run your "emulator @Galaxy_Nexus_Jelly_Bean_API_16" command

Comment: been searching for hours, got same error whether I was in `SDK/emulator/emulator` or `SDK/tools/emulator`. This is what finally solved it - thank you!

Comment: While this answer gave me the direction towards the solution to the problem. The actual problem on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine was that the emulator are located in ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator path but the emulator binary in the tools sub-directory is been execute when I ran emulator @emulator-avd. Editting the ~/.bashrc file to ensure that the emulator path get loaded before the tools path solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the emulator tool path issue. Try to specify the **full path** of your emulator path.

Try the answer from here. [Windows emulator.exe PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606128/windows-emulator-exe-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86-cpu/51627009#51627009)

Comment: Good thought!
Unfortunately, it didn't work. Added an update to my question indicating what I did when I tried using full paths and some followup attempts based on the error messages it gave me at that point.

Answer (score 1):

[Partial answer - to a related issue on the IDE]

I have faced this problem also. My Android Studio couldn't even start the emulator, coming up with an error like `"Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1"`. The fix there was to install/update the relevant system images under SDK Manager -> SDK Platforms (tab) -> Click "Show Package Details" and then "Apply".

[image: sdk manager update platforms]
[image]

However, this doesn't seem to make the CLI command `emulator -avd <avd name>` run, instead I see the PANIC error, but [apparently it's related to the migration of the emulator](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/a978kx/mac_can_run_emulator_fine_through_android_studio/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)  from the SDK path /tools to /emulator