# Run android emulator using command line

Tags: android, macos, terminal, android-emulator, command-line-interface

I am running latest version of Mac OS and I want to run android emulator through command line tool. I have run the following command on Mac terminal and got the following error.

```
 $ emulator -list-avds
Pixel_XL_API_28

 $ emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_28
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

I also run the command with available options like below that is also available on official [documentation developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

```
$ /Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_28 -netdelay none -netspeed full
```

What I need to do, so that I don't need to open android studios every time for only opening simulator.

Answer (score 5):

Please follow the steps in your terminal in Mac

```
 Step 1 ( Add Environment Variable )
 export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

 Step 2 ( .bash_profile / .bashrc ) 
 Reload you .bash_profile Or .bashrc depending on OS

 Step 3 ( go to emulator directory )
 cd /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk/emulator

 Step 4 ( Get all list of Advs  )
 emulator -list-avds

 Step 5 ( Run your Emulator Command Mode )
 emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_22_Android_5.1
```

Comment: BTW I unable to run the step 2 command but still I able to run the android simulator using command line tool. thanks, @Farid Haq

Comment: While I have follow all step and try to run final step. found error "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
"

Comment: Also ran into PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. 
 I had to specify the path to the kernel - see first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897046/mac-and-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpu

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here : [Android Emulator Error Message: "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86)

Then go as follows by cmd :

> (the path to your emulators) - C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>
>
> (the emulator name) - emulator.exe @Nexus_5 -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -writable-system