# Emulator Error: Missing emulator engine program

Tags: android, emulation

when I launch emulator I am getting error as

> Emulator: PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Win 10 , Android Studio3.1.4 , AVD Nexus 4 Api21

Comment: See answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161215/8034839

Answer (score 0):

It's usually because of avast Antivirus. Check avast quarantine file

restored emulator-arm from quarantine, added it to avast exception, paused Avast, run AVD, then resumed Avast

Credits : [PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150354/panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpus)

Comment: I dont have any antivirus.

Comment: Can u please try this
AVD Manager -> Edit -> Show Advanced Settings -> Boot Options (Selct Cold boot)

Answer (score 0):

solution for me was to replace `emulator` command with `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator`. this is for Mac, but for windows you need to adapt.